# Inserting VARBINARY(MAX) columns with MSSQL/SQLAlchemy

Tags: sql-server, sqlalchemy

It seems that the answer to this question should already be out there, but after some hours of experimentation I have yet to find a solution that works. What I'm looking to do is insert into an MSSQL database a record that includes a VARBINARY(MAX) column. The source of the data is a BLOB column from an SQLite database, also ready using SQLAlchemy and which appears to be rendered as a Python string. Whatever I try I still seem to received the following message:

> 'Implicit conversion from data type varchar to varbinary(max) is not
>   allowed. Use the CONVERT function to run this query.

I can see that what is required (or at least what seems to work if I try it manually) at the SQL level is to wrap the bound column in CONVERT(VARBINARY(MAX), ...) but making SQLALchemy do this has so far frustrated me.

Thanks in advance as always.

Comment: Facing the same error. Were you able to figure out a solution for this ?

Comment: I'm not really sure as this is from so long ago but looking over my code I see that I have done something like:

`func.CONVERT(literal_column('VARBINARY(MAX)'), bindparam('Object'))`

which uses the `func` namespace to invoke SQL functions.

Comment: For me, the problem was that I was mapping the models wrongly... I had to execute a `SQL` that showed the data types of my columns, and mapped accordingly on the models from SQLAlchemy / Flask SQLAlchemy... Changed from `String` to `VARCHAR`, and some of them changed to `Float` and `VARBINARY`.